# Form not prints post variables in action page

Tags: php, forms, post

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="http://www.example.com/product_info.php?products_id=101&amp;action=add_mult" method="post"><div class="simplebox5">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="left" class="mytable">
      <tbody><tr>
         <td class="maintop" colspan="4">

         <a title="Customer Rewards and Points" href="my_points_help.php">Customer Reward Points</a> are available for this item. Reward Points are points that YOU earn. <a title="Customer Rewards and Points" href="my_points_help.php">Details.</a>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td class="mains" colspan="4"><img src="images/icons/star.png" height="9" width="9" border="0" alt="Products name">&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;Blue Lotus</td>
      </tr>       

                <tr>
                    <td class="mains" align="left" colspan="4"><img src="images/icons/star.png" height="9" width="9" border="0" alt="In stock">&nbsp;In Stock!</td>
                </tr>
                       <tr>
    <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%"><img src="images/icons/star.png" height="9" width="9" border="0" alt="Options">&nbsp;Options&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">&nbsp;Price&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center">

         <b><a href="my_points_help.php">Reward<br>Points<br>Earned</a></b>



    </td>
    <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%">Quan-<br>tity</td>
       </tr>    

            <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            One Seed Pack<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="25"><input type="text" name="a1" value="25" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">       </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$5.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        5         </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><span style="color: #FF0000"><strong>Out<br>of<br>Stock</strong></span><input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="0"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            28 Grams Stamens<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="879"><input type="text" name="a1" value="879" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">          </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$19.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        19        </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            114 Grams Stamens<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="880"><input type="text" name="a1" value="880" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">         </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$65.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        65        </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            1 Gram 20x extract<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="236"><input type="text" name="a1" value="236" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">        </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$6.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        6         </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            3 Grams 20x Extract Powder<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="267"><input type="text" name="a1" value="267" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">        </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$15.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        15        </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            <b><span style="color: #FF0000">SALE!</span></b> 1 Kilo (2.2 pounds) Dried Flowers<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="925"><input type="text" name="a1" value="925" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">        </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$125.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
         0        </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            28 Grams Dried Flowers<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="302"><input type="text" name="a1" value="302" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">        </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$10.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        10        </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            114 Grams Dried Flowers<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="185"><input type="text" name="a1" value="185" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">       </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$35.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        35        </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>
                 <tr>
              <td class="mains" align="left" width="68%">
            454 grams (1 pound) Dried Flowers<input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="989"><input type="text" name="a1" value="989" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="b1" value="6" style="display:none">         </td>

              <td class="mains" align="right" width="12%">$100.00</td>
              <td class="mains" width="15%" align="center"> 
        100       </td>
              <td class="mains" align="center" width="5%"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0" size="3"></td>
         </tr>





        <tr>
                    <td class="main" align="center" colspan="4"><br><input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="101"><input type="image" src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_in_cart.gif" border="0" alt="Add to Cart" title=" Add to Cart "></td>

                </tr>


</tbody></table>
</div>
</form>
```

when my form submits the action executes but form post values are not getting?? any one help me

i tried all **$_REQUEST** and **$_POST** all prints only
 Array ( [products_id] => 101 [action] => add_mult )

no one getting `a[],b[],a1,b1` vales whY??

help me

Answer (score 0):

you have define the **a1** name two times that should be unique or you can define **a1[]**,

other thing is you have left **a[]** empty that should be something like this **a['value']**

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Let's test it out, add this code on the action page product_info.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Launch and submit the first page to the product_info.php and the following output should appear on the product_info.php:

```
Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 879 [2] => 880 [3] => 236 [4] => 267 [5] => 925 [6] => 302 [7] => 185 [8] => 989 ) [a1] => 989 [b] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 6 [2] => 6 [3] => 6 [4] => 6 [5] => 6 [6] => 6 [7] => 6 [8] => 6 ) [b1] => 6 [quantity] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) [products_id] => 101 [x] => 31 [y] => 11 )
```

Comment: yes i saved it as php page then i got same result but it was oscommerce page browser output . now checking my oscommerce post values